# How to force value of incorrect type into property?

Tags: typescript

Is there a simple way to force a value of incorrect type into a property? So for example, I want to set a `number` property to a `string` value.

This seems silly, but there's a good reason: it's what some outside plain javascript component *will in fact do* to instances of my class.

Here's a repro of what I want:

```
class DemoController {
    constructor(public myPercentage: number = 50) { }
}

function MyUnitTest() {
    var sut = new DemoController(25);

    // The following line simulates what an outside component will do
    // to instances, but the compiler will obviously complain about it:
    sut.myPercentage = "10";

    if (sut.myPercentage !== 10) throw new Error("Unit test assertion failed");
}
```

I've tried:

- `sut["myPercentage"] = "10";`
- `sut.myPercentage = <number>"10";`
- `var p = "10"; controller.myPercentage = p;`

But none of them worked.

Is there a way to force a string value into a number property without the compiler complaining?

---

My context, by the way is that I need a workaround for [an issue in Angular when combining `input`s of type `range` and `number`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5892), where you need to do this...

```
class DemoController {
  constructor(private $scope: ng.IScope, public myPercentage: number = 50) {
    $scope.$watch(
      () => this.myPercentage,
      () => this.myPercentage= parseFloat(<any>this.myPercentage)
    );
  }     
}
```

...because Angular accidentally set `myPercentage` to a *string*.

This context does mean my actual question is to some degree an XY-problem. In the end I'm trying to solve this Angular issue. However, at this point, I'm intrinsically curious as well how you'd solve Y: how to have a TS unit test simulate a "malicious" external bit of JS code that bypasses your type information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler does allow you to put `any`thing into a `number` property, so it will not complain about this bit of code:

```
sut.myPercentage = <any>"10";
```

Found the answer right at the end of writing my answer, sharing in case it might help someone, or in case someone has a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an angular developer, but I'm pretty sure that your problem can be solved like this:

```
class DemoController {
    private _myPercentage: number;

    constructor(myPercentage: number = 50) {
        this._myPercentage = myPercentage;
    }

    set myPercentage(value: number | string) {
        this._myPercentage = typeof value === "string" ? parseInt(value) : value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Glad I included my context. Will have a go at this solution, thx for sharing.

Comment: Confirmed this also would work (I needed a `get` too though). However, unfortunately this tells Typescript code it's "okay" to set a `string` value in my property. I prefer it to be "not okay" and have my unit test simulate the way Angular messes with my instances. - Thx again though for an excellent, working solution!

Comment: I'm not sure that it's "wrong" to set a string here, I mean, you have no control over it (if I understand you right), and so my solution says: I want to have a number, but I allow to set it in different representations and I do the converting in the setter. In the end your instance will have a number percentage and that's what you should care about.